# kendo-react-ui : Menu is not passing selected item in Select event and sometimes throwing exception while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, menu, kendo-react-ui

I have almost given-up using `Menu` class of both react component and the react-wrapper.

```
<Menu onSelect={this.onSelect}>
   <MenuItem text="First item">
       <MenuItem text="Child item"/>
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem text="Second item"/>
</Menu>
```

1. I am rendering simple `Menu` with 2 nested `menuItems` using `@kendo-react-layout` and getting following error.

> Uncaught Error: MenuItemInternal.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object. at invariant (invariant.js?4599:42)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:828)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:359)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:255)
>           at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?399b:43)
>           at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js?9682:234)
>           at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js?ab8a:701)
>           at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js?ab8a:520)
>           at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?399b:43)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:368)

2. Before that, I have been trying to use menu of jQuery wrapper i.e. `@kendo-layout-react-wrapper`. It was rendering fine, however, not passing the actual selected item in the select event object and it has to fetched thru jQuery. Sometimes `li` items add no styles/css classes and due to it, difficult to get the selected menuItem using jQuery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Update:
#2: Looks like dynamic menus are creating this issue. When you have static menu defined, it works fine .

Comment: <Menu  select={this.onSelect}>                           
                            <MenuItem>
                                <span className="k-icon k-i-columns"></span>Select 
                               {getmenuItems.call(this)}
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>

Comment: Hi, as for the native Menu I believe that there is something specific in your case because in general this work fine as shown here - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/menu/items/properties/#toc-text. Could you please provide the full code and explain how you reproduce the problem?